# validating with combination

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords

I am trying to validation on a password in javascript . Can someone shed some light on creating the perfect regular expression or another way of validating it. I tried various ways but didn't worked

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\[`, `\]`, `\-` to make it a part of the character class

```
([\d.\[!@#$%^&()\-_=+{};:,<.>\]]){2}
```

[image: REGEX]

```js
const strArr = ["1@", "11", "#$", "aa", "aa1#"];

const regex = /([\d.\[!@#$%^&()\-_=+{};:,<.>\]]){2}/g;

const result = strArr.flatMap((s) => {
  const matches = s.match(regex);
  if (matches && matches.length) console.log("NOT SELECTED");
  else console.log("SELECTED");
  return matches;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to easily understand these things to create the regex. I really had hard time generating regex

Comment: That's why I've added the image that tells you everything...

Answer (score 1):

You can abuse a lookahead on every character to determine that no index is followed by two of the specified characters.

```js
const regex = /^(?:(?![\d!@#$%^&()-_=+{};:,<.>]{2}).)+$/;

["1@", "11", "#$", "aa", "aa1#"].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str, regex.test(str));
});
```

It is a bit wasteful, but in this version it should not be a problem.
Depends on how you use that construct; what you put around/inside it.

Read about [ReDoS attacks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-redos-attack/).

Comment: Can you tell me how to easily understand these things to create the regex. I really had hard time generating regex

Comment: @curiousinlearning To easily understand *what things* ? Regexes, like programming in general, are a matter of experience; learning by doing.

Comment: using this approach if use a capital letter & then a number then it turns out it doesn't work. Say for example when I give A$ it turns to be false. How can I modify the expression to make sure it works for me.

Comment: var consecCharacter = /^(?:(?![\d!@#$%^&()-_=+{};:,<.>]{2}).)+$/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(consecCharacter)) {  
    consecnonalphacharacter.classList.remove("invalid");
    consecnonalphacharacter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    consecnonalphacharacter.classList.remove("valid");
    consecnonalphacharacter.classList.add("invalid");
  }  I am using the above code but when I pass a password like "aS1" it wont enter the if condition isntad every time it goes to else condition

Comment: @curiousinlearning this regex matches if it finds 2 consecutive non-alphabetic characters,  but `A$` does not contain that, so `false` would be the expected result.